# parses data 2 level down in flask template (render_template)

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

What are some possible ways to access the following data?

I have a data query from a database : all_data

```
@app.route('/testing',methods=['GET','POST'])
def testing():
  all_data=session.query(xxx).all()       # <----------this is my sql data I get from some query 
  .....
  render_template("template1.html", data=all_data)
```

In template1.html

- It has access to all_data
- It has a link to template2.html (using flask url_for)

Question is in template2.html, how do I access all_data? Is there anyway I can config to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will also have a Flask route which renders template2.html - so in that route you'd need to do the same SQL query to get `all_data`.

```
@app.route('/other',methods=['GET','POST'])
def testing():
  all_data=session.query(xxx).all()
  return render_template("template2.html", data=all_data)
```

Comment: render_template also works inside HTML template?

Or do I need to redirect it to a definition, and then do the query again in the def for template2.html ?

Comment: Can url_for takes a complex argument?  e.g. url_for(testing, data=all_data) and all_data is a python dictinoary